# bootstrap on ipad - carrousel not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

i use bootstrap. On the homepage i have a carrousel with a few items.(starts auto) On my desktop/latop is works fine, but on the ipad the browsers shocks when a new item loads in the carrousel.

Is this problem know and does someone know the solution?

```
carousel-inner
 .item.active
   .container
     .carousel-caption
       %p.lead 
       #{link_to t('homepage.welcome.wie_is_nice2stay'), new_lead_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'}

 .item
   .container
     .carousel-caption
       %p.lead 
         = t('houses.intro_slider')
       #{link_to t('houses.bekijk_italie'), country_houses_path(@country), :class => 'btn btn-primary'}
```

Thanks..remco

Comment: What does the "browsers shocks" mean? Can you post your code?

Comment: the screen bibbers/vibrates

updated question with code